# Is it possible to map a normal Java bean for Hibernate in a separate class / file?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have a normal model class

```
public class Person {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   ...
}
```

It's a model class and doesn't have any JPA / Hibernate annotations used.

Is it possible to somehow tell Hibernate to make this class persistent?

I want to use `Person` in queries, criteria etc, but don't want to introduce annotations to that class (it is defined in a model JAR with no JPA dependency, and I have the DB code in a different JAR);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate supports [XML mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html) to map a class to a database, as well as annotations.

Comment: yes this is nice, but is it possible to have a mapping in a separate class rather than a file?

Comment: Probably the only way to accomplish that would be through the use of inheritance.  Perhaps have a base class or interface from which you derive (or implement) an annotated version.  If you're asking if there's a way to 'sideload' annotations onto an existing class, I don't know of one, and I'm not sure what the benefit would be since the annotated class would be almost as complex as the original one.